# How to get full path / key from spring properties using SpEL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

My key is a value so I dont want to insert value to property but use keys from spring.properties. Is there a way to get that key using SpEL not simple Java?

```
@When(value=${"some.key.from.properties"})
```

I want to use keys from yml becasue compiler helps to complete it and I will not make a mistake.

Comment: You cannot inject into an annotation. Annotations are static and not resolved at runtime. The only thing you can do is to implement that logic in whatever is processing the `@When` annotation.

Comment: Ok so when I process that on The annotation I need only key. Is There A way to do it using spel?

Comment: To do what with SpEL? Annotations are nothing more then metadata and need to be static. Only your processor can replace stuff.